# Why when I assign a float number to an int variable the decimal part of the number gets assigned to my next variable?

Tags: c, variables

Here's the code I'm trying to understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    float x;
    scanf("%d%f%d", &i, &x, &j);
    printf("%d - %f - %d",i, x, j);
    return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

> 10.3 5 6

**Output:**

> 10 - 0.300000 - 5

So here's what I'm trying to figure it out

- Why when I try to assign a float value (***10.5***) to my type int variable (***i***), the decimal part of the value gets thrown into my next variable that was called in scanf (***x***)?
- What is happening that's making the computer assign 0.3 to ***x*** instead of 5?

Comment: There's no ***assignment*** in the code you show. Using `scanf` to read input isn't the same as assignment.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought that by using scanf it would be the same thing as assigning a value to the variable (like a = 1). Thank you very much for clearing that up

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The specification for `fscanf` (and hence `scanf`) in the C standard refers to the operations of putting the converted values in the pointed-to objects as “assignments.”

Comment: Perhaps you meant to scan the number into a floating point value, and then assign that float to an integer. I think that would give you the results you're expecting

Answer (score 8):

1. `%d` sees `10.3 5 6`. It reads `10` and stops at `.` because it is an invalid character for an integer.
2. `%f` sees `.3 5 6`. It reads `.3` and stops at the whitespace.
3. `%d` sees  `5 6`. It skips the leading whitespace, reads `5` and stops at the whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `scanf()` function is reading %d %f and %d in sequence, which means it will read, given your input of 10.3 5 6, the values of 10, then .3 and 5, and assign them to i, x, and j.